# Combining select statements to format output properly SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I want to combine these outputs to have one single table output instead of two. I also need to change the names of the rows from numbers to Protected and Non-Protected.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
MediaTypeID Media, count(MediaTypeID) FROM Track t
WHERE MediaTypeID = 2 OR MediaTypeID = 3;
SELECT
MediaTypeID Media, count(MediaTypeID) FROM Track t
WHERE MediaTypeID = 1 OR MediaTypeID = 4;
```

This is my out put:

```
SMedia       count(MediaTypeID)
----------  ------------------
2           451
Media       count(MediaTypeID)
----------  ------------------
4           3041
```

This is the kind of output required:

```
Media            Tracks         
---------------  ---------------
Protected        451            
non-Protected    3052
```

Comment: you can just combine these ORs into a single `SELECT`

Comment: How so? If I do that I just get one row answer. And I need to change the name of the rows in the Media column

Comment: Are you really asking how to control the output in the sqlite interactive shell? I suppose judicious use of 'as' will probably help but it's not much of a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can combine multiple queries (with the same number of output columns) with [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT 'Protected' AS Media, COUNT(*) FROM Track WHERE MediaTypeID IN (2, 3)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'non-Protected'     , COUNT(*) FROM Track WHERE MediaTypeID IN (1, 4);
```

However, to run aggregate functions with multiple groups, just use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MediaTypeID IN (2, 3) THEN 'Protected'
            ELSE                            'non-Protected'
       END AS Media,
       COUNT(*)
FROM Track
GROUP BY Media;
```